# Calculations of the error quaternion from the MSCKF paper

Tags: quaternions, kalman-filter

In the [MSCKF](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Estergios/papers/ICRA07-MSCKF.pdf) paper proposed for visual-inertial odometry, the authors use an error-state extended Kalman filter. When describing the error quaternion, they state that:

> for the quaternion a different error definition is employed. In particular, if $\hat{\bar{q}}$  is the estimated value of the quaternion $\bar{q}$, then the orientation error is described by the error quaternion $δ\bar{q}$, which is defined by the relation $\bar{q} = δ\bar{q}⊗\hat{\bar{q}}$. In this expression, the symbol ⊗ denotes quaternion multiplication.
> The error quaternion is
> $$δ\bar{q} \approx [\frac{1}{2}δ\theta^T 1]^T$$

However, I don't understand how they come up to that conclusion. I'm also struggling to understand how to calculate $δ\theta$. I've read this question that is similar: [How to compute the orientation error between two 3D coordinate frames?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3572459/how-to-compute-the-orientation-error-between-two-3d-coordinate-frames) but I'm still confuse about it! What does $δ\theta$ contain? It's a 3x1 vector right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be taken as a definition of $\delta\theta$. The quaterion $q$ is the exponential of a purely imaginary quaternion $v$ representing the axis of rotation: $q = e^{v/2}$. The factor of $1/2$ makes so that $|v|$ is exactly the angle of rotation. If we have some error $\delta\theta$ in $v$ which is small (and we ignore the commutator $[v, \delta\theta] = 2v\times \delta\theta$) then
$$
  q_{\mathrm{approx}} = e^{v/2 + \delta\theta/2} \approx e^{v/2}e^{\delta\theta/2} = q_{\mathrm{true}}e^{\delta\theta/2} \approx q_{\mathrm{true}}(1 + \delta\theta/2).
$$
This motivates us to *define* $\delta\theta$ via
$$
  \bar q_{\mathrm{true}}q_{\mathrm{approx}} = 1 + \delta\theta/2.
$$
The RHS here is the same as their awkward notation
$$
  [\tfrac12\delta\theta^T\quad 1]^T.
$$